# Unable to understand why this Jasmine test keeps failing with a timer in queue error

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, rxjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test the following function that broadcasts long press events using RxJS to subscribers

```
export function watchForLongPress(target: HTMLElement) {
  let timer: number;
  const notifier = new Subject<PointerEvent>();
  const pointerdown = (event: PointerEvent) => {
    timer = window.setTimeout(() => notifier.next(event), 500);
  };
  const pointerup = () => {
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
  };

  target.addEventListener('pointerdown', pointerdown, false);
  window.addEventListener('pointerup', pointerup, false);

  return notifier.asObservable().pipe(finalize(() => {
    target.removeEventListener('pointerdown', pointerdown, false);
    window.removeEventListener('pointerup', pointerup, false);
  }));
}
```

Below is the test to make sure that no event is broadcasted if users long-press for less than 500ms, but Jasmine keeps failing with `Error: 1 timer(s) still in the queue.` but I don't understand why. I'm using Karma as the test runner, Jasmine as the assertion library

```
  describe('#watchForLongPress', () => {

    // This test passes
    it('1. should emit after pressing on target for 500ms or longer', fakeAsync(() => {
      const target = document.createElement('button');
      const longPressListenerSpy = jasmine.createSpy('longPressListenerSpy');
      watchForLongPress(target).subscribe({
        next: longPressListenerSpy
      });
      target.dispatchEvent(new Event('pointerdown'));
      tick(600);
      target.dispatchEvent(new Event('pointerup'));
      expect(longPressListenerSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    }));

    // While this test keeps failing with `Error: 1 timer(s) still in the queue.`
    it('2. should not emit if pressing on target for less than 500ms', fakeAsync(() => {
      const target = document.createElement('button');
      const longPressListenerSpy = jasmine.createSpy('longPressListenerSpy');
      watchForLongPress(target).subscribe({
        next: longPressListenerSpy
      });
      target.dispatchEvent(new Event('pointerdown'));
      tick(300);
      target.dispatchEvent(new Event('pointerup'));
      expect(longPressListenerSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
    }));

  });
```

Comment: I assume this is because code inside `finalize` executed asynchronously. So `tick(1)` after dispatching `pointerup` should help

Comment: @OlesSavluk Thank you for the input, doing what you suggested still resulted in the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For test #2, I just changed `target.dispatchEvent(new Event('pointerup'));` to `window.dispatchEvent(new Event('pointerup'));` because in my `watchForLongPress` function, I attached the `pointerup` to `window`, not `target`, and even doing `target.dispatchEvent(new Event('pointerup', { bubbles: true }));` still doesn't make the dispatched event bubble up to `window` in a test environment.